# How to sort Data Frame elements on external indexing in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I would like to find a simple solution for a sorting problem with data frame. After carefully analyzing all the posts on the topic, I realized that despite several pretty cumbersome ways (extracting indices, adding columns, re-indexing, etc...) there is no simple solution for my problem. So maybe somebody have an illuminating idea)

Here is the problem (resized into a basic example):

I have a DataFrame say DT1 with some data. DT1 has a set of indices Ind corresponding to each row of data (x,y,z):

```
DT1 = [Ind Datax Datay Dataz]
      [12       x1  y1  z1]
      [25       x2  y2  z2]
      [38       x3  y3  z3]
      [55       x4  y4  z4]
      [99       x5  y5  z5]
```

On the other hand I have an numpy array say A1, with some data that must be sorted. The rows numbers (but not the indices!) of the A1 correspond to the row numbers of DT1.
The idea is to sort DT1 on the sorting performed on A1.

```
A1 = [14] - Row 1
     [94] - Row 2
     [38] - Row 3
     [9]  - Row 4
     [55] - Row 5
```

After sorting A1 descending, we get (including old rows tags):

```
A1 = [94] - Row 2
     [55] - Row 5
     [38] - Row 3
     [14] - Row 1
     [9]  - Row 4
```

So the corresponding DT1 sorted on the new A1 should look like:

```
DT1 = [Ind DataX DataY DataZ]
      [25       x2  y2  z2]
      [99       x5  y5  z5]
      [38       x3  y3  z3]
      [12       x1  y1  z1]
      [55       x4  y4  z4]
```

Anybody has a quick and elegant solution to do that? I can add that the final indices are not themselves relevant, since data from DT1 is exported elsewhere as it is.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround, which is pretty simple. It worked fine for my particular example, but still I'm sure a more elegant solution exists. It is done in 4 separate steps:

1. Numpy array (on which the sorting has to be done) is converted to DataFrame1. By converting to DataFrame1, an ascending index from 0 to n is automatically created.
2. In the initial DataFrameInitial (which has to be sorted) the old index is reset to a new one (ascending index from 0 to n, exactly the same as in DataFrame1).
3. The DataFrameInitial is combined with the DataFrame1 to get DataFrameSortable
4. The sorting routine is applied on DataFrameSortable using the column from DataFrame1.

The key element is to reset the indexes in DataFrameInitial, because the combination must be done on the same indexes. Otherwise a the combined DataFrame has non overlaping rows. It is also included in the example below.

The following code shows the enumerated steps and the example of erroneous combination:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


Data1 = [[1,3,5,7,10],[4,8,4,5,6],[2,4,5,1,1],[4,9,5,9,1],[1,2,3,6,7],[5,3,3,2,3], 
[4,7,9,0,6],[4,0,0,1,8],[3,6,5,2,1],[6,0,3,8,6]];

DF1 = pd.DataFrame(Data1);
DF1.columns = ['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5'];
DFN2 = DF1.iloc[5:10]

Narr1 = ([[14],[94],[38],[9],[55]]);
DFNarr = pd.DataFrame(Narr1);

DFN2bis = DFN2.copy(); # The old indices are kept
DFN2.reset_index(inplace = True) # Replacing old indices by ascending ones

# Combining with same indices in both DataFrames
DFNcomb = pd.concat([DFN2,DFNarr[0].rename('sort')], axis=1);

# Sorting on initial Numpy array values
DFNcomb = DFNcomb.sort_values(by=['sort'], ascending=False);

# Here below is the example of what happens during combination of 2 DataFrames if the 
# indexes are not reset

# Combined with non-overlaping indices in both DataFrames
DFNcombErroneous = pd.concat([DFN2bis,DFNarr[0].rename('sort')], axis=1);
```